# Recommended way to handle missing AngularJS directive attributes

Tags: angularjs

Here's a simple directive expecting a `details` attribute:

```js
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .directive('myCustomer', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                details: '=' // required, rather than the optional '=?'
            },
            templateUrl: 'my-customer.html',
            link: function(scope) {
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.details.length; i++) {
                    // do stuff
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

if this is then called without the required attribute:

```
<my-customer></my-customer>
```

then the following error message is currently displayed:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

are people checking that their directives are correctly being utilised and if so, is there a common / recommended way of performing this error handling or just ad hoc (as below)?

```
        link: function(scope) {
            if (scope.details) {
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.details.length; i++) {
                    // do stuff
                }
            } else {
                // error handling here
            }
        }
```

Comment: I guess not. How sad. React handles this much better. It seems like there should be a standard way of doing this, like you suggested with `=?` syntax (`=!` for required?). Seems like the directive should be able to specify the attribute requirements.